# nginx serving only / but not any other files

Tags: docker, nginx

I have two docker containers as below:

```
nginx ==> working as proxy web server (nginx web server)
dist  ==> working as a php-fpm container
```

And this is my `dist.conf`:

```
server {
    server_name dist.me.com;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass dist:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/dist_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/dist_access.log;
}
```

The issue is if I enter `dist.me.com`, it shows my `index.php` contents fine. But if I enter `dist.me.com/index.php` or `dist.me.com/index2.php`, I get error **404 Not Found**.

I tried changing some values of `conf` file but it did not help me.

Both `index.php` and `index2.php` exist in `/var/www/html` path.

Comment: It seems that's exactly what your `dist.conf` is designed to do. Notice that the `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$)` block is marked as `internal`, and the `location ~ \.php$` block simply returns 404.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried removing `location ~ \.php$ { return 404; }` but it did not help me. By `... block is marked as internal`, I tried removing `internal;` line but did not help me. Could you help me more?

Comment: Try removing `internal` **and** changing `~ ^/index\.php(/|$)` to `~ \.php(/|$)`

Comment: @RichardSmith that worked, thanks:) Please write this as an answer so that I can vote you up for this favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing `dist.conf` is *designed* to block URIs ending with `.php`. The `internal` directive prevents a location from being directly accessed, and there is also a location which explicitly returns 404 for any URI ending with `.php`.

You need to change the `location` rule, remove the `internal` directive, and delete the `location` block which follows it.

For example, replace `location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) { ... }` and `location ~ \.php$ { ... }` with the single `location` block as follows:

```
location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass dist:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```