# FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream nginx error

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, fpm

I user nginx docker as  proxy server, and there are other containers running: `nuxt.js` and `php-fpm`.

This is my `fpm`'s `conf` file:

```
server {
  server_name fpm.me.com;
  root /var/www/fpm/html;

  location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  #location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68350978/nginx-serving-only-but-not-any-other-files
  location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    #internal;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    return 404;
  }
  access_log off;
  error_log /dev/stderr;
}
```

But when I type `fpm.me.com`, I get this error in `nginx`'s `log` file:

```
2021/08/03 09:31:18 [error] 31#31: *13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: MY_IP, server: fpm.me.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.20.0.8:9000", host: "fpm.me.com"
```

I saw other answers in StackOverFlow, ServerFault and other websites but it seems it did not help me.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look valid:

```
fastcgi_pass fpm:9000
```

You have 2 options:

- use a unix socket:

  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
- use TCP port

  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

Option 1 is slightly faster and doesn't have the risk of ports exhaustion if you receive many concurrent connections.

Comment: Why `fastcgi_pass fpm:9000` is not valid? I use this conf file in another server (but there only exists one application and container). And since it's dockerized, `nginx` and `fpm are two separate containers

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `volumes` I mounted for `nginx` and `fpm` which were not the same.

This is my `compose` file:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - './fpm/:/var/www/fpm/'
  fpm:
    image: custom
    volumes:
      - './fpm/:/var/www/'
```

While it should have been like this to work:

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - './fpm/:/var/www/fpm/'
  fpm:
    image: custom
    volumes:
      - './fpm/:/var/www/fpm/'
```